# How to add multiple prdoucts including their id, qty and price as a single transaction to a Access database?

Tags: vb.net

I have a shopping cart page which lists 12 books with 12 buttons assigned each to a book item, the user is able to click each button and add the price and qty to a Session in VB. So if a customer wants to order all 12 books they would click all twelve buttons and the price and qty of each product would be added to a Session. My problem is when the customer completes the form validation how do I assign all 12 items with their sessions to a MS Access database in a single transaction using session.id?

```
Protected Sub order_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    If (Page.IsValid) Then

        Dim strSessionID As String
        strSessionID = Session.SessionID
        Dim strFullname As String
        Dim strAddress As String
        Dim strPostcode As String
        Dim intCardNo As Long
        Dim strCardType As String

        Dim dateOfOrder As Date
        dateOfOrder = Session("dateOfOrder")

        Dim  dblTotalCost As String
        dblTotalCost = Session("dblTotalCost")

        Dim intProduct001 As String
        intProduct001 = Session("product001")
        Dim intProduct002 As Integer
        intProduct002 = Session("product002")
        Dim intProduct003 As Integer
        intProduct003 = Session("product003")
        Dim intProduct004 As Integer
        intProduct004 = Session("product004")
        Dim intProduct005 As Integer
        intProduct005 = Session("product005")
        Dim intProduct006 As Integer
        intProduct006 = Session("product006")
        Dim intProduct007 As Integer
        intProduct007 = Session("product007")
        Dim intProduct008 As Integer
        intProduct008 = Session("product008")
        Dim intProduct009 As Integer
        intProduct009 = Session("product009")
        Dim intProduct010 As Integer
        intProduct010 = Session("product010")
        Dim intProduct011 As Integer
        intProduct011 = Session("product011")
        Dim intProduct012 As Integer
        intProduct012 = Session("product012")

        strFullname = fullname.Text
        Session("fullname") = strFullname
        strAddress = address.Text
        Session("address") = strAddress
        strPostcode = postcode.Text
        Session("postcode") = strPostcode
        intCardNo = cardN0.Text
        Session("CardN0") = intCardNo
        strCardType = cardType.Text
        Session("CardType") = strCardType
        Dim strDatabaseNameAndLocation As String
        strDatabaseNameAndLocation = Server.MapPath("ecommerceDatabase.mdb")
        Dim strSQLCommand As String
        strSQLCommand = "INSERT INTO Orders(SessionID, orderDate, orderTotal ) " & _
            "Values ('" & strSessionID & "','" & dateOfOrder & "','" & dblTotalCost & "');"
        Dim objOleDbConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        objOleDbConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0; Data Source=" & strDatabaseNameAndLocation)
        objOleDbConnection.Open()
        Dim objOleDbCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
        objOleDbCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(strSQLCommand, objOleDbConnection)
        objOleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        objOleDbConnection.Close()

        Dim strDatabaseNameAndLocation2 As String
        strDatabaseNameAndLocation2 = Server.MapPath("ecommerceDatabase.mdb")
        Dim strSQLCommand2 As String
        strSQLCommand2 = "INSERT INTO Customers(SessionID, Fullname, Address, Postcode, CardNo, CardType) " & _
            "Values ('" & strSessionID & "', '" & strFullname & "', '" & strAddress & "', '" & strPostcode & "', '" & intCardNo & "', '" & strCardType & "');"
        Dim objOleDbConnection2 As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        objOleDbConnection2 = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0; Data Source=" & strDatabaseNameAndLocation2)
        objOleDbConnection2.Open()
        Dim objOleDbCommand2 As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
        objOleDbCommand2 = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(strSQLCommand2, objOleDbConnection2)
        objOleDbCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery()
        objOleDbConnection2.Close()

        Response.Redirect("validate.aspx")
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to run all of your SQL commands using a single connection, and call [`OleDbConnection.BeginTransaction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yx87ys5.aspx) on the connection, and [`OleDbTransaction.Commit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbtransaction.commit.aspx) on the returned transaction object.  You should put your product IDs into a `List(Of String)` to minimize the code, and you should [parameterize your queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx) to avoid SQL injections issues.

The following pseudocode illustrates the general idea:

```
Dim productIDs = New List(Of String)()
productIDs.Add(Session("product001")) ' Should be in a loop!
' etc.

Using cn = New OleDbConnection(...)
    cn.Open()
    Using tran = cn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable) ' or other isolation level

        Using cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql1, cn, tran) ' Customers
            ' Set command parameters
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using

        Using cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql2, cn, tran) ' Orders
            ' Set command parameters
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using

        For Each productID In productIDs
            Using cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql3, cn, tran) ' OrderProducts?
                ' Set command parameters
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        Next

        tran.Commit()

    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Still a bit confused, how would all selected items be added to the orders table? what about the price and qty should that be in an Array? I want all selected items to be added to the orders table with the session id as a single transaction? help?

Comment: I'm afraid that with the information you have provided, I don't see how you expect to store the selected items in the orders table, since you only show `SessionID, orderDate, orderTotal` as columns.  This was what I was hinting at with the 3rd command in the loop over productIDs - that you probably need a 3rd table to store the order items, but the provided pseudocode was simply to show how to handle multiple commands in a transaction, not to write your code for you.